# How to export data from the database into .csv format programmatically?

Tags: java, mysql, database, csv

I have stored some data in MySQL database through a java program. Now I want to export that data from the same program in .csv file.

I know One method of doing this is to get all the fields of one row in variables and then store them in a file by seperating them with a comma(,) and by repeating the same for every row in the database.

But I want to know that Can I export the same data through any other way through java in .csv format.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't use `mysqldump`?

Comment: Maybe he wants to do it programmatically?  I came across this question because I want to give users of our web app the ability to dump search results to CSV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this once it worked for me.
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Honestly, unless you want to do something fancy, what you are doing should work

Answer (score 2):

You can Google for a third party CSV library, do the Java querying yourself with sqljdbc.jar or whatever is appropriate to your database, and feed the data to the CSV library.

You might even find a third-party library that can give you a CSV from a SQL query and a JDBC connection.

But if you're going to programmatically implement CSV, please implement it completely, including escaping spaces, quotes, etc.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_Rules) has details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL take a look at [mysqldump](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-MySQL-Database/)